# Drop Duplicate in market data

Tags: python, pandas

So let's assume we have market data updates that we are looking at.

```
 1. Bid 1 Ask 1.5
 2. Bid 1 Ask 1.5
 3. Bid 1 Ask 1.5
 4. Bid 1.5 Ask 2
 5. Bid 1.5 Ask 2
 6. Bid 2 Ask 2.5
 7. Bid 2 Ask 2.5
 8. Bid 2 Ask 3
```

I'm looking to use drop_duplicates on this to keep only the times that the bid or ask changes. I tried

```
df.drop_duplicates(cols=['Bid,Ask'])
```

But it didn't come out how I expected. The behavior I want in this list would be to condense the list into(Assume the number is the index, so keep index)

```
 1. Bid 1 Ask 1.5
 4. Bid 1.5 Ask 2
 6. Bid 2 Ask 2.5
 8. Bid 2 Ask 3
```

**So it would be drop the row if both the bid and the ask are the same as the row before it.**

Any obvious ways to do this?

Comment: Fixed your output, it was assuming the markup was a numbered list, changing the markup to code retains the display you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.shift()` to shift a column, and use `any` to check for differences.  For example, given a frame like

```
>>> df
   Bid  Ask
1  1.0  1.5
2  1.0  1.5
3  1.0  1.5
4  1.5  2.0
5  1.5  2.0
6  2.0  2.5
7  2.0  2.5
8  2.0  3.0
>>> df[(df != df.shift()).any(axis=1)]
   Bid  Ask
1  1.0  1.5
4  1.5  2.0
6  2.0  2.5
8  2.0  3.0
```

---

Step-by-step, we shift down 1:

```
>>> df.shift()
   Bid  Ask
1  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  1.5
3  1.0  1.5
4  1.0  1.5
5  1.5  2.0
6  1.5  2.0
7  2.0  2.5
8  2.0  2.5
```

We compare the dataframe with its shifted version:

```
>>> df != df.shift()
     Bid    Ask
1   True   True
2  False  False
3  False  False
4   True   True
5  False  False
6   True   True
7  False  False
8  False   True
```

And then we make a series which is True only if either of these are true and a row differs from the next row:

```
>>> (df != df.shift()).any(axis=1)
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to remove duplicates - you want to remove subsequent rows which are identical. Because same bid-ask pair can occur several times during the day, not necessarily consecutively. I'd loop through the dataframe like this:

```
for i in df.index:
    if(i-1 in df.index and df['Ask'][i]==df['Ask'][i-1] and df['Bid'][i]==df['Bid'][i]):
        df = df.drop([i])
```

I'm sure there can be a more elegant solution to this, but this is the general idea you can find useful...